# How to show a Dialog on Android using the reveal effect from material design?

Tags: android, animation, android-alertdialog, material-design

I have an `Activity` with a `FloatingActionButton`. When I press the FAB, an `AlertDialog` is shown. I want to animate its appearance by using something like reveal effect or curved motion from `Android`'s `Material Design`. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Reveal) only has an example for changing visibility of existing views.

How can I achieve that for an `AlertDialog`?

Answer (score 3):

I did something similar by calling the dialog's `setOnShowListener` before I show the dialog. I still need to refine the animation, but it is a start:

```
dialogToAnimate.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {
    @Override public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // Remember that ViewAnimationUtils will not work until API 21.
        final View view = dialogToAnimate.getWindow().getDecorView();
        final int centerX = view.getWidth() / 2;
        final int centerY = view.getHeight() / 2;
        // TODO Get startRadius from FAB
        // TODO Also translate animate FAB to center of screen?
        float startRadius = 20;
        float endRadius = view.getHeight();
        Animator animator = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, centerX, centerY, startRadius, endRadius);
        animator.setDuration(1000);
        animator.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: I updated my answer to use an existing API on Dialog.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a custom view (defined in a XML) you can try this:

```
AlertDialog a = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)...blablabla;
View v = a.findViewById(R.layout.example);

// get the center for the clipping circle
int cx = (v.getLeft() + v.getRight()) / 2;
int cy = (v.getTop() + v.getBottom()) / 2;

// get the final radius for the clipping circle
int finalRadius = Math.max(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());

// create the animator for this view (the start radius is zero)
Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(v, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);

// make the view visible and start the animation
v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
anim.start();
```

To hide it using the reverse animation:

```
View v = <yourAlertDialog>.findViewById(R.layout.example);

// get the center for the clipping circle
int cx = (v.getLeft() + v.getRight()) / 2;
int cy = (v.getTop() + v.getBottom()) / 2;

// get the initial radius for the clipping circle
int initialRadius = v.getWidth();

// create the animation (the final radius is zero)
Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(v, cx, cy, initialRadius, 0);

// make the view invisible when the animation is done
anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
        v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
});

// start the animation
anim.start();
```

Comment: What would you suggest for a similar animation for API level <21?

Answer (score 1):

Alert Dialog With Reveal Effect for above API 21=>

```
public final void customAlertDialog(final Activity mActivity)
 {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);
        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(mActivity).inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_simple_msg,null);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(view);
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        TextView tvOk= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvOk);
        final Animator[] animHide = {null};
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            alertDialog.show();
            view.post(new Runnable() {
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int cx = (int)view.getWidth() / 2;
                    int cy = (int) view.getHeight() / 2;
                    float finalRadius = (float) Math.hypot(cx, cy);
                    Animator animVisible = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);
                    animHide[0] = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, cx, cy, finalRadius, 0);
                    animVisible.start();
                }
            });
        }
        tvOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    if ( animHide[0]!=null)
                    {
                        animHide[0].addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                alertDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        animHide[0].start();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }
```